# Is there a way to register multiple instances of a class from inside a loop in python?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, class, instance

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self,attribute)
        Example.attribute=attribute


def function(data):  #data in the form of an array
    for i in range(len(data)):
        instance_storage.append(Example(data[i])


instance_storage=[]
function(some_array)
for instance in instance_storage:
    print(instance.attribute)
```

This is a model of what I'm doing currently however the print statement at the end prints a repeat of the last instance indicating that all of the instances are simply copies of the last instance made. Is the anyway to avoid this?

Comment: Use `self.attribute = attribute` in the init method, you're setting a global value to the class itself, not the instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correctly creating multiple instances of the class-ie objects. However in the constructor you are setting the attribute on the class itself, not the objects, and there is only one copy of the class itself. You want:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self,attribute)
        self.attribute=attribute
```